# ClickOnce downloads an old version

Tags: clickonce

The situation :
I deployed a WPF soft with ClickOnce. The installations and updates are OK since the beginning (used by several users both on local network and internet since several years). We have several versions (alpha, beta...) each available on different publication sites.

Recently a user had to install the newest alpha version. That user used to only have the beta version several months ago.
That user is on a far local network, internet being in between ours and his. Plus, he has a proxy that we can't deactivate for security reasons.

The problem :
The version that this user gets is an old beta version. Not the version published on the site that holds the newest alpha version.

What has been tested since :

- empty the web browser cache (files, download, cookies)
- See in the AppData if there are still file from the old version (only empty folders)
- execute rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache
- republish the soft
- restart the publication site
- deactivate the publication sites of other versions
- check if there was still files from old versions in the publication site folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so outside the user's network, the downloaded version is the good one.
We'll try something like that :
http://www.geektieguy.com/2007/08/25/troubleshooting-clickonce-deployment-issues/
And I'll update if it helps.

Comment: So the problem was the user's proxy (squid) cache

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be useful for someone having similar problems but with different reason: there is also another scenario when one can encounter situation that lower version from the server would be treated as an update for higher version installed on Windows. If your lower version was deployed to your server but it hasn't checked the option "The application should check for updates" (Project properties / Publish / Updates) or in .application xml tag "subscription" but a higher one has this option checked, then the current version would ask for installing the older one from the server as an update.